# A branch of an if-statement cannot be just a declaration?

Tags: c++, if-statement, syntax, grammar

> A branch of an if-statement cannot be just a declaration. If we need to introduce a name in a branch, it must be enclosed in a block.------by TC++PL 4th.

```
void f1(int i)
{
    if (i)
        int x = i + 2;        //error: declaration of if-statement branch
}
```

But it makes sense on compilers of VS2013 and GCC4.8.

And Working draft(N3242) shows me that

> If the substatement in a selection-statement is a single statement and not a compound-statement, it is as if it was rewritten to be a compound-statement containing the original substatement.

the code can be equivalently rewritten as:

```
void f1(int i)
{
    if (i) {
        int x = i + 2;
    }
}
```

Thus after the if statement, x is no longer in scope.

So what is the standard?

Comment: "But it makes sense on compilers of VS2013 and GCC4.8." - no it doesn't, it's just that these compilers accept the nonsense.

Comment: Likely the latter is going to be the new standard, even if it looks quite ugly to me :)

Comment: @user3477950 But how do you explain the working draft...

Comment: @Huang-zh The explanation is that the new working draft is not the same as the current standard. So, it contains different stuff. What a surprise, really.

Comment: Well, one may call the entire C++ to be a set of nonsenses and shortcomings :)

Comment: @OP. The reason why the first one is bad is because if you declare x in the first line of the if statement like that (without the curly brackets), then the variable x is immediately destroyed after the statement is ran. You cannot even get the value of x either. That's why it's non-sense. If x was declared before the if statement, that's a different matter.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear.

Comment: `warning: unused variable ‘x’ [-Wunused-variable]`, so what is the point anyway?

Comment: @user3477950: I don't believe there's any relevant difference in this area between the working draft and the current standard -- or in *any* C++ draft or standard. If you know of one, please cite it.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: The example is not useful, but suppose the purpose of a declaration is to invoke a constructor and/or destructor. It's not necessarily good style, but it's perfectly legal.

Comment: @KeithThompson +1 I see your point. I actually found myself doing that once or twice lol. I didn't think about it when reading OP's post or when I did it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Syntactically, a declaration can be a statement. Specifically, it's a *declaration-statement*.

(I say "can be" because not all declarations are statements. For example, a declaration at file scope, where a statement cannot legally appear, is not a statement.)

Since the syntax of an `if` statement is:

```
if ( condition ) statement
```

or

```
if ( condition ) statement else statement
```

it's perfectly legal for either branch of an `if` statement to be a declaration.

In your example, it's not particularly useful, but I can easily imagine that you might want to declare an object for the purpose of executing its constructor and/or destructor.

> A branch of an if-statement cannot be just a declaration. If we need
>   to introduce a name in a branch, it must be enclosed in a
>   block.------by TC++PL 4th.

I have a PDF copy of "The C++ Programming Language", 4th edition, 4th printing, dated April 2015. The statement in 9.3 that "A declaration is a statement." is still there. That statement is incorrect, or at least incomplete. The statement that:

> A branch of an if-statement cannot be just a declaration. If we need
>   to introduce a name in a branch, it must be enclosed in a block.

is no longer there; it's been updated to:

> The scope of a declaration of a branch of an if-statement is just that
>   branch. If we need to introduce a name in a branch, it must be
>   enclosed in a block (§9.2).

That's not *strictly* correct, but it's true that if you want a declaration in a branch, you need to enclose it in a block if you want to refer to it in a statement.  A branch consisting of just a declaration is legal but usually not useful.

(Incidentally, C has different rules. C has permitted mixed declarations and statements since the 1999 standard, but it doesn't treat declarations as statements, so in C a declaration *can't* be a branch of an `if` statement.)

Comment: 4th also states that declarations are statements.I am really confused now."a declaration is a statement."statement->declaration statement->block declaration. But,declaration also contains other declaration(such us template-declaration, empty declaration..etc).

Comment: So,"a declaration is a statement.",may means "A block declaration is a statement" but not all declarations?

Comment: Right, not all declarations are statements, only those that appear in a place where a statement is legal. For example, a declaration at file scope, outside any function definition, is not a statement.

Comment: Now I know the meaning of "can be" in your first sentence.Thanks you!

Comment: @Huang-zh: I thought I saw a green check mark on my answer, but it's not there now. Did you intend to accept this as the correct answer? (It's entirely up to you whether you do so or not.)

Comment: I do want to accpet.but damn the net laaaaaaaaaag..I really appreicate you. please forgive me.. I try to click the check mark several times and no responding...and that leads what you saw on your screen,sry..

Comment: @KeithThompson "Right, not all declarations are statements, only those that appear in a place where a statement is legal. For example, a declaration at file scope, outside any function definition, is not a statement." It's defintetely not in agreement with the standard. TC++PL v4. 9.3 "A declaration is a statement". "File scope" is a global scope.

Comment: The question still stands. Precisely contrary to what the book states it is still legal in all c++xx standards. Verified on g++.

Comment: @iantonuk: What question still stands? The statement in TC++PL that "A declaration is a statement" is incorrect or at least incomplete. I can't find the statement, quoted in the question, that "A branch of an if-statement cannot be just a declaration." I do see a similar statement (perhaps it was corrected in a later edition): "The scope of a declaration of a branch of an if-statement is just that branch. If we need to introduce
a name in a branch, it must be enclosed in a block (§9.2)." (Probably should be "in a branch", not "of a branch".)

Comment: Please read the The C++ Programming Language Edition 4 paragraph 9.3 with the code exactly as quoted in the answer. It says in the comment that it is an error(it wouldn't compile). However it DOES.

Comment: "A declaration is a statement" is incorrect or at least incomplete. I'm sorry but between you and Bjarne Stroustrup, I think people would choose the latter as authority on C++. Otherwise please provide clear and explicit proof.

Comment: @iantonuk: I have a PDF copy of "The C++ Programming Language", 4th Edition, Fourth Printing, April 2015. Section 9.3, "Declarations as Statements", does not show an example of code that is expected to fail compilation. In the ISO C++ standard, (I'm looking at the 2011 edition), the grammar says that a *declaration-statement* is a kind of statement, consisting of a *block-declaration*. A *block-declaration* is one of several kinds of *declaration*. For example, a *function-definition* is a kind of *declaration*, but it cannot be a *statement*. (Terms in italics are defined in the grammar.)

Comment: @iantonuk: You mentioned "the code exactly as quoted in the answer". There is no C++ code quoted in my answer.  Did you mean the code quoted in the question? I can believe that that code appears in an earlier printing of TC++PL, but it's not in the one I have.

Comment: I meant the question.

Comment: void f1(int i)
{
    if (i)
        int x = i + 2;        //error: declaration of if-statement branch
}

Comment: @iantonuk: To be clear, does that example appear in TC++PL 4th edition? If so, it appears to have been corrected in the 4th printing.

Comment: I'm sorry, the exact paragraph is 9.4.1, right in the end.

Comment: @iantonuk: I see it. The comment on the declaration in the 4th printing is "// declaration on if-statement branch"; it's not an error. The following line is "++x; // error: x is not in scope". The declaration is not an error; the reference to it is. https://imgur.com/a/K7e9bj4

Comment: It explicitly says void f1(int i) { if (i) int x = i + 2; //error: declaration of if-statement branch }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170974/discussion-between-keith-thompson-and-iantonuk).